# need an architectural suggestion

Tags: c#, sql-server, database-design

Here's what I am trying to achieve.

I have a SQL server database with 16 tables.

Now I need to generate a flat file as following.

```
Field1, value1,value2, ..., valueN
Field2, value1,value2, ..., valueN
Field3, value1,value2, ..., valueN
.
.
.
FieldN, value1,value2, ..., valueN
```

Where Fields are **similar** to Column names in **multiple tables**. However its not the same name. There is a 1 to 1 relation between Field and column names.

How should I do this?

Thank You

How about importing as XML and then doing and XSLT?

Comment: I think you need to define what you mean by "similar." And if you tell us why you are trying to accomplish this it might be easier to get an answer. Is this to populate tables with test data? Is it to move data from one table layout to another?

Comment: @MJB By "similar" I mean there is 1 to 1 relation between Field and columnName. e.g. UnitSerial column must be "Unit Serial" field in the flat file. And no, its not always a difference of space in between. There is just no consistency.

Comment: @MJB I am trying to integrate two systems and this flat file is what the second system accepts.

Comment: Now that I have several options. What's the best approach? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I would tend to want to import the data AS IS into the new system, and then convert it using SQL. That would allow you some leeway in terms of decodes, lookups, etc, as well as transactions.

Comment: How about importing as XML and then doing and XSLT?

Comment: If XML/XSLT is your strength, then I think that is an acceptable solution. However, even if SQL is not your strength, I think it would still be a good choice. You get so many extra benefits, such as being able to compare the tables after you've built them, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Being very general here, but you could load the table output resultset into a 2d array and then traverse the array in column-major order to output the file.

You could also create an array that maps the columns positions or names to field names.

pseudocode:

```
fieldName[] = {"Field1","field2",....}

String results[][] = getDBResults()  
for( i=0;i&ltnumCOls;i++ ) {  
    line = fieldName[i] + ",";  
      for(j=0; j<&ltnumRows; j++) {  
          line += results[j][i] + ",";  
      }
      FILE.writeline(line[:-1]);  
}
```

Comment: How about importing as XML and then doing and XSLT?

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved in few steps:

1. Load data from database along with column names.
2. Transform column names to something acceptable.
3. Transform all data into correct format.
4. Generate the file.

The whole thing is as generic as your question. If you asked specific question, then maybe we can give you specific answer.

Comment: How about importing as XML and then doing and XSLT?

Answer (score 0):

Use `PIVOT`.

I wrote [a blog post about using PIVOT](http://nathandewitt.net/blog/2009/09/21/pivot-and-unpivot/).  You won't need to do the same kind of aggregation that I was doing, but this should get you started.

Comment: How about importing as XML and then doing and XSLT?

Answer (score 0):

To get your field names as you wish, you may need an intermediate mapping table, which you fill by hand:

```
MyField         FieldNameNeeded
UnitSerial      Unit Serial
Address1        Address Line 1
```

Comment: How about importing as XML and then doing and XSLT?